# Directory creation using brace expansion

Tags: linux, bash, brace-expansion, mkdir

mkdir Public/1 2 3 ----- This line creates folder 1 in the Public folder and  creates folders named 2 and 3 in my pwd.

mkdir Public/{1..3} ---- This line creates folders 1,2,3 in Public only as expected.

Can someone explain what is happening.

Comment: I checked.It does not create, but can you explain how does bash interpret this. Why only 1 was created in Public and others in the pwd.

Answer (score 2):

Your first command is this:

```
mkdir Public/1 2 3
```

BASH interprets `mkdir Public/1` as creating a directory called `1` inside of the Public directory. The others, `2` and `3`, don't have a directory prepended to them so BASH interprets it as creating them in the current working directory.

Your second command is this:

```
mkdir Public/{1..3}
```

As you have `Public/{1..3}`, BASH interprets this as using brace expansion to create directories `1`, `2`, and `3` inside of the `Public` directory instead of the current working directory as in the first command.

The same would occur if you were to use the same with `rmdir` or `touch` instead of `mkdir`.

Answer (score 1):

In `mkdir Public/1 2 3` there are three arguments: `Public/1`, `2` and `3`. The command is equivalent to

```
mkdir Public/1
mkdir 2
mkdir 3
```

In `mkdir Public/{1..3}` the shell expands `{1..3}` before `mkdir` runs. But the shell doesn't expand `{1..3}` *alone*. Here `{1..3}` is a part of a *bigger "word"*. `Public/{1..3}` expands to `Public/1 Public/2 Public/3`. You can see this with `echo`:

```
echo Public/{1..3}
```

The real command run by the shell was `mkdir Public/1 Public/2 Public/3` which is equivalent to

```
mkdir Public/1
mkdir Public/2
mkdir Public/3
```

Comment: Thank you,this solved almost all of my problems. Btw can we use this sort of expansion with copy...like cp file_name /home/karan/Public/{1..5}.......I tried this but didn't work as it is asking to use the -r option but this option is only required for directories whereas I am trying to copy a file into multiple locations.

Comment: @LuciferG `cp` takes just one target; it can take multiple sources though. `cp a b c` copies `a` and `b` to `c`. It doesn't matter if `b` and `c` come from a single expansion *in the shell*; `cp` is not aware of what the shell did first. My general answer to "how to copy to multiple destinations?" is [here](https://superuser.com/a/1064516/432690). For a single file [use `tee`](https://superuser.com/a/32634/432690).

Comment: So unlike cp, mkdir can take multiple arguments i.e mulitple paths whereas cp can take a single arguments i.e a singe path?

Comment: @LuciferG `cp` accepts multiple operands, but only one of them is the destination. See `man 1 cp`.